# Modular nth roots, e.g. $x^5 \equiv 6 \pmod{31}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms, modular-arithmetic

I want to algorithmically solve the (large integer) modular root equation 
$$x^n \equiv a \pmod {p^k},$$
assuming for simplicity that $p$ is prime, $\gcd(a,p)=1\;$ and $n$ odd. If $q \equiv n^{-1} \pmod {\varphi(p^k)}$ exists, then using Euler's theorem a solution is 
$$x \equiv a^q \pmod {p^k}$$
But how to compute  $x$ if $q$ does not exist, i.e. if $\gcd(n,\varphi(p^k))\ne 1?$

An example would be $x^5 \equiv 6 \pmod{31}.\;$ Solving the similar 
$x^5 \equiv 6 \pmod{29}\;$ is easy: $x\equiv 6^{17}\equiv 13 \pmod{29}$

Are there practical algorithms without using primitive roots or the complete factorization of $p-1?$

Comment: You are in fact asking whether discrete logarithms ar not so good an idea to use in cryptography after all

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen: I just want to expand my multi-precision library to include such roots, modular square and cube roots are already implemented. There are no intended relations to discrete logarithms or cryptography. The restriction on primitive roots and/or factorization of $p-1$ is there because factorization is hard in general.

Comment: You can try to find the primitive roots in $\pmod{p}$ and, and then check if they are also primitive $\pmod{p^k}$. The rest would be easy. I have no idea about the complexity of finding the primitive roots, but it would work for multiple values of $a$, if you're trying to find the answer for several $a$

Comment: @gammatester did you ever figure this out? I'm facing the exact same problem where $\gcd(n,\varphi(p))\ne 1$

Comment: @martin: Unfortunately not.

Comment: @gammatester i found a paper: https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/117.pdf check section 4 for an example, it's pretty straight forward. However, this will only give you a root that is in the multiplicative group generated by $a$ (feels like there is only one root within that group?). I was hoping for a way to find _all_ roots mod p

Comment: @martin: Thank you for the link. I did a quick and dirty look at the paper. I cannot see how it could be used to solve $x^5 \equiv 6 \pmod{31}.$ IMO this method is not applicable because $31=6\times 5 +1$ so you have $l>r,$ or do I miss something obvious? Since one solution is $26$ and $26 \equiv 6^5 \pmod {31}$ it should give this as one solution according to your "However ...".

Comment: @martin: Got it, with $r=5, s=1, l=1$ we have $q=31 \equiv l\times r^s + 1 \pmod{ r^{s+1}}$. So according to Table 1 we have a solution $x=a^{\frac{4q+1}{25}}=a^{5}\pmod {31}$ and this gives
$x\equiv 6^5 \equiv 26 \pmod {31}$.

Comment: @gammatester great! still, it would be great if we could find all the other roots as well (11, 13, 21, 22). They won't appear in the group generated by $a$ so I guess something more clever than simple exponentation is needed

Comment: @gammatester fwiw, I just realized you can find all the other roots simply by multiplying your one root $x$ with any element of order $n$ repeatedly. Every multiplication will give you another solution, $n$ solutions in total before you get back to $x$ again. In your case we would take the solution $x=26$ and generate the other roots with an element of order 5, e.g. the number 2. Then we get $x(2^1)=21, x(2^2)=11, x(2^3)=22, x(2^4)=13$ Easy! :)